# A branch shows as N commits behind master (due to a revert), when it should be N commits ahead

Tags: git, merge, rebase, revert

The repo I'm working on does not use `master` as the bleeding edge, they use a `develop` branch. `master` is used to follow the latest release. Thus, `master` should always be *behind* `develop`.

I did not realize this workflow, and pushed a documentation fix (involving things like README files) to `master`. As a simple example, our site used to be on Sourceforge, and I updated the readme to talk about GitHub instead.

Because I then realized I was on the wrong branch, I reverted things. In GitHub land, the way to do this is with another merge request that basically reverts your first commit.

My `master` branch currently shows Sourceforge-related wording in my READMEs. My `develop` branch currently shows GitHub-related wording.  But the `develop` branch is 16 commits *behind* `master`.

Using GitHub's "merge" function shows me a diff that would *revert* my docs, just like the `master` branch was reverted.

So far, the only fix I've found is to manually merge the 16 commits, but de-conflict them by manually discarding all the changes. Obviously the commits that update the docs already happened in develop, because the words are correct.

Using either `git rebase master` or `git merge master` in the develop branch blows away my changes.  I need, effectively, a "db-only" merge.

Comment: Can you show the commit graph you would like to have, and what you have now instead?

Comment: Revert, in Git, does not mean "revert to" but rather "add something that undoes". So in general, reverting pushes you further ahead. This is often desirable, and hence often desired. When and whether it's *your* desire is another question entirely and requires a lot more information than you've provided. See @mkrieger1's comment above as well, but look up the difference between the misnamed "revert" and `git reset`.

Comment: So I've figured this out, simply enough, the answer is: On the develop branch, I did `git merge -s ours master`, which pushed those 17 commits into my develop branch again, but discarded their texts.  At some point in the future, when we cut a new release (which is the only time master gets touched) those changes will finally make it to Master, as a single diff, which being all-docs, is fine from a `git blame` pov.

Answer (score 0):

Merging back `master` to develop is one solution.

The other, depending on the level of communication between the team, would have to `reset --hard` your `master` branch and force push it immediately, making sure your teammates are aware of that, and fetch the new `master` history immediately as well.
That way, no need to revert/merge and mess up the history.
But that would mean no other commits would have been pushed to `master` at the time of the reset.